# I want to know how to create a line chart with chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am doing front end development and would like to create a graph like the one in the image in chart.js.

I don't know how to do the following part.

- How to make the background grid a dotted line
- To start the 'CP' of the x-axis tick marks where it overlaps with the y-axis tick marks, instead of starting a little to the right
- The outer frame should be surrounded by a solid black line.

**Code**

```
  function createChartConfig(ctx) {
        return {
          type: "line",
          data: {
            labels: ["CP", "NP", "A", "FC", "AC"], // X-axis labels
            datasets: [
              {
                label: "My Dataset", // Dataset label
                data: [35, 60, 40, 55, 85], // Y-axis data points
                backgroundColor: "rgba(135, 206, 250, 0.2)", // Background color of the line area
                borderColor: "rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)", // Border color of the line
                borderWidth: 3, // Border width of the line
                pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)", // Color of the points
                pointBorderColor: "#fff", // Border color of the points
                pointBorderWidth: 2, // Border width of the points
                pointRadius: 5, // Radius of the points
                fill: false, // Fill area under the line
                tension: 0.1, // Bezier curve tension
                borderDash: [6, 6],
              },
            ],
          },
          options: {
            responsive: true,

            scales: {
              y: {
                type: "linear",
                borderDash: [8, 4],

                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                ticks: {
                  stepSize: 5,
                },
                gridLines: {
                  // You can change the color, the dash effect, the main axe color, etc.
                  borderDash: [8, 4],
                  color: "#348632",
                },
              },
              xAxes: [
                {
                  gridLines: {
                    // You can change the color, the dash effect, the main axe color, etc.
                    borderDash: [8, 4],
                    color: "#348632",
                  },
                },
              ],
            },
            plugins: {
              borderColor: "red",
              borderWidth: 2,
              borderDash: [5, 5],
              borderDashOffset: 2,
            },
            layout: {
              padding: {
                // Add padding to avoid cutting
                top: 10,
                right: 10,
                bottom: 10,
                left: 10,
              },
            },
            elements: {
              line: {
                borderWidth: 2, // Border width of the line
              },
              point: {
                radius: 5, // Radius of the points
              },
            },
          },
        };
      }
```

[Figure I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R76KJ.png)

[Current figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnRMb.png)

I have looked in the official chart.js docs, articles, chatGPT, etc., but I can't seem to find a way to do it. In particular, I can't seem to find a way to make the background grid dotted.

Comment: Have you tried the grid: {borderDash: [ ]}

Comment: Your image shows a dashed gridline, and in your question, at the very end, you mention the dotted grid. Which one of the two do you want? What is your ChartJS version?

Comment: I have tried the grid{borderDash} but it didn't work.

Comment: @FiddlingAway
I want to achieve the first image chart.

Comment: Which version of chart.js do you use? Some of your options are specific to v2 (`scales.xAxes: [...]`) others are from newer versions (`scales.y:{...}`)